# Am I allowed to ask a reference-request question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to find a good source for learning web scrapping with R so that I can get data from Google Flights. On other site such as math.stackexchange, there is a reference - request tag; however, this site does not have it. Would my above question be welcome here?

I wasn't sure what to tag this question.

Comment: For research like this, if simply searching the web is not sufficient, you can try more sites with more relaxed rules, like for example Quora or Reddit.

Comment: "Can you please google this for me" questions are always very poorly received.  Not so obvious to me why the math site don't mind them, but it does have a very unusual history.  Used to be MathOverflow, a site that wasn't part of the SE network.  Well, scientists do march to a different drummer.  Programmers try very hard to copy each other's work, scientists always have to avoid it :)

Comment: I'm surprised that Google's ToS allows that.

Comment: @MartinJames You mean writing an R program to pull data?

Comment: @Helix noo.. I'm pretty sure that it's clear that I was referring to 'get data from Google Flights', you know, with my reference to 'Google's ToS'?

Answer (score 8):

No, since it's off-topic.

Any request for an off-site resource is off-topic here. Requests for tutorials and learning resources are specifically off-topic.